# Get Xrange of current graphics object in IDL

Tags: object, graphics, idl-programming-language

How do I get the X-range of the "current" graphics object? For example lets assume I create a single plot window:

```
p = plot(/test, xrange=[10,35])
```

Now, without using the reference to **p** how do I get the X-range ([10,35]) of this plot window?

Comment: what do you mean by *"without using the reference to p"*? if you have the plot object assigend, you could just do `p.XRANGE`...

Comment: I'm not sure if this works when using the plot function (as opposed to the plot procedure), but you may be able to use `!x.crange`

Comment: @MRFuppes For example the case when I have overwritten p.

Comment: @SteveG Sadly this contains [0,0] when using the plot function.

Comment: well, then avoid overwriting the variable ;-) for example you could store plot objects in an `OBJARR` and obtain properties if needed. just make sure to add a check if the object still exists (might have been closed), see `OBJ_VALID`.